# How to get bpm_outcome by Activiti workflow javascript in Alfresco

Tags: javascript, workflow, task, alfresco, activiti

I'm struggling to get "bpm:outcome" variable in my task through a simple "complete" ScriptTaskListner. I add i'm using Activi WorkFlow Engine.

This is my attempt:

```
var import = task.getVariable('bpm_outcome');
```

It is strange...the value returned is "Next" (!!?!?)

Anyways...i've read that maybe this could do the job:

> TaskInstance ti = ... 
>   ti.getVariableLocally("bpm_outcome");

or

> ti.getVariable("bpm_outcome");

but i can't get the taskinstance...any suggestion?
The other "wf:..." variables are perfectly captured with a simple task.getvariable attempt.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Activity (unlike JBPM) there is no other outcome than Next/Done.

If you look at the default review and approve workflow of Alfresco, you'll notice they've introduced a new variable to see what the outcome is:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
                  <activiti:field name="script">
                     <activiti:string>
                        execution.setVariable('wf_reviewOutcome', task.getVariable('wf_reviewOutcome'));
                     </activiti:string>
                  </activiti:field>
               </activiti:taskListener>
```

The task model:

```
<property name="wf:reviewOutcome">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <default>Reject</default>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint name="wf:reviewOutcomeOptions" type="LIST">
                            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                                <list>
                                    <value>Approve</value>
                                    <value>Reject</value>
                                </list>
                            </parameter>
                        </constraint>
                    </constraints>
                </property>
```

The share config:

```
<field id="wf:reviewOutcome" label-id="workflow.field.outcome" set="response">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl" />
               </field>
```

So Alfresco just uses a normal field to determine the outcome. So you syntax is ok, you just need to get the right variable. In this case it's **task.getVariable('wf_reviewOutcome')**

Comment: Actually i suspected it. Malik you are great as usual, i would like to contact you asap, is it possible, is against rule to share my mail?

Comment: Hi Mark, If you click on my profile you'll find details to my linkedin/twitter there you can contact me ;)

Comment: eehehe yes i  know...the fact is i didn'join them either. I'll be a twitter man, i suppose.

Comment: If you click on the website in my profile, drop your contacts and I'll try to contact you.